# extracting string from file using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a json response from where I need to read only the path name and write to an output file

```
"path":"path1","url":"URL1"},"changeType":"edit"},{"item":{"version":138390,"size":2209,"hashValue":"CJkHrcI2FSKb3IoIGr/g/g==",
"path":"PATH2","url":"URL2"},"changeType":"edit"},{"item":{"version":138390,"size":25263,"hashValue":"OU0Rf623p47fTt4ASnSGOA=="
```

and I want my output file to have just 
PATH1
PATH2

how do i use regex to achieve this? or any other easier way to do this?

Comment: Please [format your code and sample input/output properly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/22189/248777).

Comment: Your Json don't seem to be valid.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61994959/edit) your question and show us **valid** json.

Answer (score 1):

Please format your json properly and then you may use something like this to get the path value

```
(Get-Content "<path of json file>" | ConvertFrom-Json).item.path
```